# GridBagLayout not using anchor

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, gridbaglayout

here i'm trying to anchor the components(buttons) to the side of the panel but i'm obviously missing something with my GridBagConstraints. I'd like them to have padding if possible; any idea how i would do something like this [image] ? Could I just use Insets for the padding? Cheers for any help.

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PlayGamePanel extends JComponent{

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    JComponent GamePanel2() throws IOException {

        JComponent GamePanel = new JLabel();

        //Setting up the gridbaglayout
        GamePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbLayout = new GridBagConstraints();

        /*//Creating a button to test out switching panels
         * 
        JButton testButton = new JButton ("test");
        GamePanel.add(testButton);*/

        //Creating buttons for answering the quiz

        gbLayout.gridx = 0;
        gbLayout.gridy = 0;
        gbLayout.weightx = 1.0;
        gbLayout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbLayout.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20);

        JButton AnswerOneButton = new JButton("Answer One");
        GamePanel.add(AnswerOneButton);
        GamePanel.add(AnswerOneButton, gbLayout);

        gbLayout.gridx = 0;
        gbLayout.gridy = 0;
        gbLayout.weightx = 1.0;
        gbLayout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
        gbLayout.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20);

        JButton AnswerTwoButton = new JButton("Answer Two");
        GamePanel.add(AnswerTwoButton);
        GamePanel.add(AnswerTwoButton, gbLayout);

        gbLayout.gridx = 0;
        gbLayout.gridy = 0;
        gbLayout.weightx = 1.0;
        gbLayout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
        gbLayout.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20);

        JButton AnswerThreeButton = new JButton("Answer Three");
        GamePanel.add(AnswerThreeButton);
        GamePanel.add(AnswerThreeButton, gbLayout);


        gbLayout.gridx = 0;
        gbLayout.gridy = 0;
        gbLayout.weightx = 1.0;
        gbLayout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
        gbLayout.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20);


        JButton AnswerFourButton = new JButton("Answer Four");
        GamePanel.add(AnswerFourButton);
        GamePanel.add(AnswerFourButton, gbLayout);

        return GamePanel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `GridBagConstraints` to the container when you add the components...

For example...

```
GamePanel.add(AnswerOneButton, gbLayout);
```

You also need to supply the cell position for each component, for example...

```
gbLayout.gridx = 0;
gbLayout.gridy = 0;
JButton AnswerOneButton = new JButton("Answer One");
GamePanel.add(AnswerOneButton, gbLayout);
```

Will place the `AnswerOneButton` button in the first column of the first row.

You can supply padding to each cell by using the `insets` property, for example...

```
gbLayout.weightx = 1.0;
gbLayout.gridx = 0;
gbLayout.gridy = 0;
gbLayout.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20);
JButton AnswerOneButton = new JButton("Answer One");
GamePanel.add(AnswerOneButton, gbLayout);
```

Now, personally, I would use `NORTHEAST`, `NORTHWEST`, `SOUTHEAST` and `SOUTHWEST` as anchors, it just makes more sense to me...

```
gbLayout.weightx = 1.0;
gbLayout.gridx = 0;
gbLayout.gridy = 0;
gbLayout.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20);
gbLayout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
JButton AnswerOneButton = new JButton("Answer One");
GamePanel.add(AnswerOneButton, gbLayout);
```

After updating all the constraints for all the buttons I get something like ...

[image]

You may want to take a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details...

You may also like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code ;)

It's also a rather interesting choice to use `JLabel` as your primary container, you may find `JPanel` provides better support

**Updated with example code**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout();
    }

    public TestLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(GamePanel2());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    JComponent GamePanel2() {

        JComponent GamePanel = new JPanel();
        GamePanel.setOpaque(false);

        //Setting up the gridbaglayout
        GamePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbLayout = new GridBagConstraints();

        /*//Creating a button to test out switching panels
         * 
         JButton testButton = new JButton ("test");
         GamePanel.add(testButton);*/
        //Creating buttons for answering the quiz
        gbLayout.gridx = 0;
        gbLayout.gridy = 0;
        gbLayout.weightx = 1.0;
        gbLayout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbLayout.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20);
        JButton AnswerOneButton = new JButton("Answer One");
        GamePanel.add(AnswerOneButton, gbLayout);

        gbLayout.gridx = 1;
        gbLayout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
        JButton AnswerTwoButton = new JButton("Answer Two");
        GamePanel.add(AnswerTwoButton, gbLayout);

        gbLayout.gridx = 0;
        gbLayout.gridy = 1;
        gbLayout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
        JButton AnswerThreeButton = new JButton("Answer Three");
        GamePanel.add(AnswerThreeButton, gbLayout);

        gbLayout.gridx = 1;
        gbLayout.gridy = 1;
        gbLayout.weightx = 1.0;
        gbLayout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
        JButton AnswerFourButton = new JButton("Answer Four");
        GamePanel.add(AnswerFourButton);
        GamePanel.add(AnswerFourButton, gbLayout);

        return GamePanel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the link, will give that a read. About the code, I think it should work well but it's only sending it to the far left of the line instead of the top left of the container. Just tried using NORTHEAST as well with no luck. EDIT: Didn't see your edit, will try that all now, thanks!

Comment: Hey, thank's for all your help but I still can't get it to work - I edited my code so far into my original post; I have a feeling it's to do with my weightx values. Is there any chance I could see your code for comparison?

Comment: You need to modify the `gridx` and `gridy` values according to the cells you want the buttons to appear, using `0` means they are all in the same cell...